# Using Jenkins with Unity test Framework

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up a test system using the Unity Test framework ( [Unity Test framework](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity)) and Jenkins.

In Unity, the Test are executed using a makefile, using the single command line *make*.  This is working as it should from the command line.
I have copied my source tree and test environment to the server containing my Jenkins instance.
I can get Jenkins to run a simple echo "Hello World" job, but when I replace the build steps with the make command I get errors.

> Started by user user
> Running as SYSTEM
> Building in workspace /bitnami/jenkins/home/workspace/EdTest
> [EdTest] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins9549502869208287065.sh

- cd /home/bitnami/Unity/examples/EdTest
- make
  rm -f test1.out
  rm: cannot remove 'test1.out': Permission denied
  make: *** [makefile:63: clean] Error 1
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
  Finished: FAILURE

Do I need to change permission of the folder containing my source code?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that the makefile executed correctly after changing the owner of my source code to jenkins.